# How do I really know who is accessing my server?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, ip, adsl

Recently I started using my old desktop computer as a server, I installed Ubuntu server 18.04 and it's now connected to my router (Huawei HG532s). I also have a web page (Only for testing) and an SSH server to log in and monitor the server from anywhere (obvious) and the problem comes now:

I have the server connected to the router and the router (ADSL) is connected to the internet. I have set up the router to forward any request that wants to connect via port 80 or 22 to the private IP of the server. And now, whenever someone connects to my web server, the access logs shows me that all petitions are coming from the same IP (My public IP) and same with SSH, whenever I connect to my server, when I type the command `who` it shows me I'm connected from my public IP. 
I know that problem it's because it's my router who is forwarding the packaged and requests but I would like to know if there is any kind of "solution" to this so I'm able to actually know who is establishing a connection to my server.

Thanks in advice and sorry if I misspelled, trying my best to write this correctly.

Output of `who` command:

```
alex@ubuntu:~$ who
alex    pts/0     2019-02-07 07:22 (62.37.40.224)
alex    pts/1     2019-02-07 07:22 (62.37.40.224)
```

Output of the `traceroute` command to my server's IP from my university’s network:

```
traceroute to 62.37.40.224 (62.37.40.224), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
   192.168.212.254 (192.168.212.254)  3.004 ms  2.972 ms  2.947 ms
   172.29.34.1 (172.29.34.1)  7.755 ms  7.736 ms  7.686 ms
   1.red-81-46-16.customer.static.ccgg.telefonica.net (81.46.16.1)  7.662 ms  7.621 ms  7.584 ms
   217.red-217-124-114.static.ccgg.telefonica.net (217.124.114.217)  15.257 ms 217.124.112.37 (217.124.112.37)  20.113 ms 217.124.114.217 (217.124.114.217)  20.108 ms
   * * *
   157.red-80-58-84.staticip.rima-tde.net (80.58.84.157)  14.988 ms  15.931 ms  15.895 ms
   145.red-80-58-97.staticip.rima-tde.net (80.58.97.145)  15.865 ms * *
   80.58.106.58 (80.58.106.58)  14.724 ms  14.712 ms  14.687 ms
   241.red-80-58-88.staticip.rima-tde.net (80.58.88.241)  14.661 ms  14.635 ms  14.615 ms
  10.21.0.1 (10.21.0.1)  14.565 ms  14.475 ms  20.228 ms
  10.21.0.2 (10.21.0.2)  20.180 ms  20.143 ms  20.111 ms
  172.27.111.22 (172.27.111.22)  15.212 ms  15.175 ms  15.005 ms
  172.27.111.51 (172.27.111.51)  14.931 ms  14.818 ms  14.807 ms
  172.27.111.126 (172.27.111.126)  14.797 ms  14.776 ms  14.762 ms
  172.27.111.10 (172.27.111.10)  19.592 ms  16.708 ms  16.622 ms
  193.152.56.1 (193.152.56.1)  19.503 ms  19.474 ms  19.407 ms
  80.58.72.149 (80.58.72.149)  19.399 ms  19.356 ms  19.292 ms
  * * *
  * * *
  216.184.113.180 (216.184.113.180)  23.230 ms  17.892 ms *
  * * *
  * * *
  * 193.251.247.14 (193.251.247.14)  16.104 ms *
  * * *
  * * *
  * * *
  * * *
  * * *
  * * *
  * * *
```

Apache2 log after access with my 4G IP:

```
90.174.4.159 - - [07/Feb/2019:10:20:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 774 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
```

Command `who` output after logging in with my 4G IP:

```
alex     pts/0        2019-02-07 09:35 (192.168.1.254)
alex     pts/1        2019-02-07 09:16 (62.37.40.224)
alex     pts/2        2019-02-07 10:19 (62.37.40.224)
alex     pts/3        2019-02-07 10:44 (62.37.40.224)
```

Comment: Have you had someone *else* try to connect? Cause any connections from you would be from *your* ip address... your ip address would be both the destination (which then gets NATed to the internal network ip of the server) and the source.

Comment: As @CliffArmstrong has suggested... a basic test would be to use your mobile phone 3G/4G and visit your website/log on to your SSH and then check the logs to see if your 3G/4G IP address is logged...

Comment: Originally posted at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116327/how-do-i-really-know-who-is-accessing-my-server, see also the comments there.

Comment: `90.174.4.159 - - [07/Feb/2019:10:20:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 774 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"` Oh yes, if I get into my web page from my 4G IP address it shows it... Why doesn't it show it when I log in with my univeristy proxy?

Comment: @xBeiker Have you also tried SSH from the phone (e.g. using [Termius](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/termius-ssh-client/id549039908))?

Comment: @Melebius I've updated the post (at the end) to show the output of `who` when I log in with my 4G IP and the access log of apache2. Btw thanks for showing mi Termius.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this will be a problem with the way your router is handling inbound connections. It appears to be proxying them or translating the source address as well as the destination - when it.should.only be doing the latter.

Comment: I've updated the post (at the end) to show the output of `who` when I log in with my 4G IP and the access log of apache2 in case it helps...

Comment: What ypu have provided in your update shows everythings is correct, and your router is not ptoxying or rewriting source addresses. Without some kind of authentication or tie-in with a third party, the best you csn get is the remote parties purported IP address, ehivh is coming yhtough uniquely as per your tests.

Comment: But whenever someone logs in via SSH it's not showing me his IP address, it's showing my own public IP adress

Comment: Yes, you are correct - your router appears to be having difficulty with handling SSH traffic correctly.

Comment: I guess I can't do anything to solve that problem, isn't it?

Comment: You can.   The problem exists on the router, so you would need to fix it theore (or if it is not fixable there, replace the router).  You may also be able to work arround it by changing the port SSH listens on - especially SSH runs on the router.   Another solution would be to use a VPN to connect to the box, and then SSH over that - which is a more secure solution as well.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I forgot to explain that I use both 22 and 443 ports to access via SSH since my university's proxy has port 22 unaccesible, but when I use it on my phone I'm using the 22 port and it shows the same